# Output is not giving garbage value

Tags: c

Good evening guys, 
This is a little program shown below. I'm seeking for garbage value of b in every execution, but get the same answer.
The code is simple as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 300, b,c;
    if (a>=400)
    b=300;
    c=200;
    printf("\n%d\n%d",b,c);
    getch();
 }
```

The o/p in Codeblocks is as follow

```
2
200
```

but if I remove the line

```
b=300;
```

keeping the semicolon, then it gives garbage values.

Why is this contradiction happening?

Comment: Undefined behavior is just undefined behavior. It's not guaranteed to be "wrong", "random", "garbage" or anything else.

Comment: Does here "if" condition affect the execution & assignment of value of b?

Comment: @userXXX yes, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading uninitialized variable follow below rules,

Static variable are by default initialized to zero means local static or file scope variable (global one).

Non-static variables which local to function are indeterminate.  Reading them prior to assigning a value results in **undefined behavior**. compiler is free to do any thing. It can be zero, it can be the value that was in there, it can crash the program. you have absolutely no guarantees.

It  will simply give you the last value that was stored in that position on the stack (or in that register if the variable happens to be stored in a register).

Also **undefined** might be different between different compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 is garbage only, you should print the value of b before 'if-statement' and see if it matches with the last print statement. If it matches then both are garbage values and no change occurred to them because of the 'if-statement'.

The question about how compiler generates a garbage value is unpredictable/random.

Comment: Hi there, i just did what you said & its showing output as:
    2

Comment: Then 2 is the garbage your compiler is generating. On my machine the compiler is generating 482 as value of b.

Comment: ok  I am getting the thing. Just one more thing , Have an eye on this little bit modified program of upper version:

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(void)

{
    int a = 300, b,c;
    printf("%d ",b);
    if (a>=400)
        ;
        printf("%d %d",b,c);
        getch();
}


Here i get constant value of b for every execution, but c varies. Is there any concept or just random behaviour of compiler.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

**Step 1:**  `int a = 300, b, c;` here variable `a` is initialized to `'300'`, variable `b` and `c` are declared, but not initialized.
**Step 2:** `if(a >= 400)` means `if(300 >= 400)`. Hence this condition will be failed.
**Step 3:** `c = 200;` here variable `c` is initialized to `'200'`.
**Step 4:** `printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c);` It prints `"300, garbage value, 200"`. because variable `b` is not initialized.